# How to retrieve page id from application tab

Tags: facebook

I have an application tab installed on many pages that i manage.

I want to retrieve the ID of the page where i am but the signedRequest not contain the page_id. Why?

This is my code:

```
if (response.status === 'connected') {

      var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
      var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
      var signedRequest = response.authResponse.signedRequest;
      var data = signedRequest.split('.')[1];
      data = JSON.parse(window.atob(data));
    }
```

The output of data is:

```
Object { 
  algorithm="HMAC-SHA256",
  code="AQBQcCt1SoKkiTUT_PnwL-Gx...nA-Izqqk6TRrsfqIIkp8kae",
  issued_at=1445942158,
  user_id=my_id
}
```

How can i get the page id?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Page ID is in the `signed_request` parameter, and that one will get sent to your server with POST: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/canvas/login#parsingsr

Just parse it and use `var_dump` to check out the fields.

You can also use the PHP SDK to get the parameter: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_access_token_from_page_tab/5.0.0

Comment: hey, i post my code, but in the signedRequest there is not the page id. Can you help me?

Comment: then either your app id or secret is wrong, or you don´t try it on a page. of course the page id is only available if you open the app in a page tab.

Comment: i read that the page info is send only in the signed_request that gets POSTed to your app on initial load into the iframe – and with JavaScript, you have no access to POST data. The signed_request you get from the JavaScript SDK is a “different one”, it contains info about the auth status and user only, not about the page.  So i must use a server side language to retrive the page id. It's true?

Comment: of course, yes. that code in the links of my answer is php, for example.